# Regex.replace issues

Tags: regex, vb.net

First of all, this is KIND OF a repeat of a very common topic, but I'm having specific issues and everything I've found here and elsewhere online doesn't seem to change my results, so I'm posting.  Hope someone can give it a quick glance and tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Trying to remove odd characters from file names and blurbs from those files from an indexed search using REGEX.Replace.  I need to keep periods, underscores, hyphens... basically the only characters I know I need out are double quotes, <'s and >'s... so here's one line of code...

```
Dim replaced As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[^A-Za-z0-9_. ]+", " ")
```

it's still filtering out periods and hyphens and underscores.  No idea why.  I've tried adding the \ character before the symbols, no change... so like JS.Slider comes back as JS Slider, no matter which weird example expression I pull online... can someone either really briefly explain how regex works (specifically how I've got it wrong) or explain a quick way to filter without losing the periods etc?

Comment: Your regex looks fine, do you really want to replace with a space ?

Comment: That's weird, the regex is valid. Just to be sure that it's not the problem of compilation process, can you change `" "` to `"x"` and check the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `space` and `dot` unicode characters:

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "[^\w\u002E\u0020\u00A0]+", "X")
```

Regex Explanation:

```
[^\w\u002E\u0020\u00A0]+

Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\w\u002E\u0020\u00A0]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
   Unicode character U+002E «\u002E» (dot)
   Unicode character U+0020 «\u0020» (space)
   Unicode character U+00A0 «\u00A0» (space)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove these chars `"<>` do this

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "[""<>]", "", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```